# Cumulative sum of rows in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe which I get a value for each year and state :

```
  0  State   1965   1966    1967    1968
  1  Alabama 20.2    40     60.3     80
  2  Alaska   10     15      18      20
  3  Arizona  5      5       10      12
```

I need each value sum the last with the current one :

```
  0  State   1965   1966    1967    1968
  1  Alabama 20.2   60.2   120.5    200.5
  2  Alaska   10     25      43      63
  3  Arizona  5      10      20      32
```

I tried `df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)` and `.cumsum` but I don't know how to apply it to my problem, as I don't need a new column with the total sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with `axis=1` and convert non numeric column `State` to `index`:

```
df = df.set_index('State').cumsum(axis=1)
print (df)
         1965  1966   1967   1968
State                            
Alabama  20.2  60.2  120.5  200.5
Alaska   10.0  25.0   43.0   63.0
Arizona   5.0  10.0   20.0   32.0
```

Or select all columns without first and assign back:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(axis=1)
print (df)
     State  1965  1966   1967   1968
0                                   
1  Alabama  20.2  60.2  120.5  200.5
2   Alaska  10.0  25.0   43.0   63.0
3  Arizona   5.0  10.0   20.0   32.0
```

Comment: Solved using 'df.set_index('State').cumsum(axis=1)'
Many thanks!!!